# How to get boxplots using ggplot to overlap instead of faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am new to ggplot, and using ggplot to show box plots of my data corresponding to different types like this. There are four types. I found that I can use facet_wrap to generate four different graphs.

```
ggplot(o.xp.sample, aes(power, reduction, fill=interaction(type,power), dodge=type)) +
   stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')+
   geom_boxplot() + 
   facet_wrap(~type)
```

My question is, I want to combine all the four graphs into one graph such that each type has a different color (and slightly transparent to show other plots through). Is this possible?

Here is the data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9589729

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: Your graph contains so much information that I don't think that presenting everything on one graph is a good idea. Visualisiong statistical data should be as simple as possible, that when you see it you know everything. Nonetheless providing example data will be appreciated. How many interactions is in your data?

Comment: I am trying to add data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

o.xp.sample = read.csv("C:\\...\\data.csv",sep=",")

ggplot(o.xp.sample, aes(factor(power), reduction, fill=interaction(type,power), dodge=type)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 3)) #added line as suggested by Paulo Cardoso
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to add `guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 3))` for legibility.